# Flutter Responsive Design For All Platforms

Tags: flutter, dart, coding-style, responsive

Any recommendation for responsive ui flutter package or layout builder.

I have used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil but it does not fulfills the requirement.

Comment: packages like that only works on mobile phone, but what if user opened your app in an ipad or tablet? this was my problem before so i ended up creating my own responsive layout

Comment: Layout builder right.. That would be a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MediaQuery,Expanded as well as responsive frameworks...
I Think this comment will helpful...

Comment: Thanks for ur comment i will use these techniques.